# How to have nested routes without nested templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have ember routes set up like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource("subreddit", { path: "/r/:subreddit_id" }, function() {
          this.resource('link', { path: '/:link_id'} );
        });
      });
```

But I want the to view each link in a completely separate template. In other words, I want to render a different block of html, rather than render the link html into subreddit's {{outlet}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit `/r/xxx` in the browser Ember will look for two templates related to `subreddit`.  First it looks for `'subreddit'` and then it looks for `'subreddit/index'`.  If '`subreddit`' if found, then it is rendered and then if `'subreddit/index'` is also found, it is rendered into the `{{outlet}}` of `'subreddit'`.  If `'subreddit'` is not found Ember will just move on to `'subreddit/index'`.  The `'subreddit'` template is also rendered for any sub-paths that are nested under `/subreddit`, such as the `'link'` template for `/r/xxx/yyy`.  `'subreddit'` is kind of like a "per model layout" template that allows you to wrap (decorate) all of the sub-path templates.

Something like this should let you keep your nested routes, and allow you to use Ember default behavior.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subreddit">
  <p>A static header bar for this subreddit could go here, or not.</p>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subreddit/index">
  <p>
    All of the details of the subreddit go here, this will be rendered
    into the {{outlet}} of "subreddit".
  </p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="link">
  <p>
    Link view goes here.  This template will replace "subreddit/index" 
    in the {{outlet}} of "subreddit".
  </p>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I make my models available to me in subreddit/index instead of just subreddit?

Comment: You also have a `SubredditIndexRoute` and `SubredditIndexController`.  You can pretty much just rename the `Subreddit` ones, or you could potentially define your own version of those two and then use `needs` and property bindings to access the model of `SubredditController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the links in separate templates you should not nest your routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("subreddit", { path: "/r/:subreddit_id" });
  this.resource('link', { path: '/:link_id'});
});
```

A different approach you can take could be to use named outlet's and override `renderTemplate` of the corresponding route and render the template in the place of the named outlet's, have a look here for more info on that: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I wanted access to :subreddit_id in a non-nested route?

Comment: @Brandon, that's why I proposed the different approach, so you can keep your nested routes and render the templates in different named outlet's